# .net Webforms 5 steps data form data from client and submit to the server

Tags: .net, form-submit, webforms

I like to ask what's the best way to submit a form with 5 tabs.

Is like, i need to get some data content in input fields and the form contains 5 tabs in html, and i need to send all data to the server.

My ideia is, send like a object to the server with my all data filled.

- Using cookie to saves the data than i'm choosing, and in the last step i send the cookie to the server. (CONS - And if the cookies in browsers are disabled..) - 1 postback only
- Using viewstate to holding data but 2 problem aproaches the postback and the viewstate on each multiview index change.
- Using session to holding data but postback already is a problem.

Sory my english, but appreciate help however. THanks

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the tab control inside the form tag. Then use the collections exposed by the tab control or ASP.NET's request object to access the values. You don't say which tab control you are using so I will just assume you forgot to included the control inside the form tag. Also be sure to include the appropriate runat attribute in the markup for the tab control.